# jQuery - Display occurrence number of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html...

```
<div class="display">sometext</div>
<div class="display">sometext</div>
<div class="display">sometext</div>
```

Using jQuery I want to be able to click the first `div` and an alert is displayed saying that you have clicked the first `div` and so on. I know how to count the number of `div`s with a specific class but not how to tell which one is clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about 'first' as such, but you could try:

```
$('.display').click(
    function(){
        alert("You clicked div number: " + ($(this).index('.display') + 1) + ", of " + $('.display').length);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g2hqW/).

References:

- [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: Ahhh .index, I think that is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: um, in what way is it complicated?

Comment: Nvm, you just made it look complicated :-P It's the same approach as mine using .index, although you should cache your selector so it doesn't have to go find all divs on each click.

Answer (score 7):

Behind the scenes, `.index()` also loops through all previous elements. The following alternative is more efficient than `.index()` when the element has lots of siblings.

```
$(".display").each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert("Clicked div.display, number " + i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice use of a closure. Actually internally jQuery use the `inArray` function which checks to see if the browser has indexOf, if it does then it uses `indexOf.call(...)` to return the index, if not then yes it does loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way.

```
$divs = $('.display'); 
$divs.click(function(){
     alert( $divs.index($(this)) ); 
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KU5DB/) to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple and proven by [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nPtA/):

```
var containers = jQuery('.display');
containers.bind('click', function(event){
    alert('Clicked element no. ' + (containers.index(this)+1));
});
```

Please let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can do just:

**HTML**

```
<div class="display" name="1">sometext</div>
<div class="display" name="2">sometext</div>
<div class="display" name="3">sometext</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.display').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/SzwJU/

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery? You can write a simple javascript that is triggered onclick by the div.

Comment: Maybe the OP already use jQuery for something else in the page, and usually using jQuery will make your code shorter.